# Is it normal for a newly grown fig foliage to hang down like this?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants

This particular foilage just grew out pretty fast. But it's hanging down. It's soft; as they all are when they first start growing, but I don't remember if I've ever seen them hanging down. The stalk at the bottom is very strong and where the hanging foiliage is; is soft. I'm assuming that it's still growing. Also, how can I add another fig to the pot? Can I cut off any part of the fig and pot it inside the pot? Can this plant handle a humidifier? I keep it under a humidifier from time to time. Any help?

**UPDATE** I've changed the pot to a ceramic pot and also changed the dirt. Now for some reason, my fig is dropping. I've had it in the sun; when the sun comes out. Hoping my plant isn't in the process of dying. I've attached a picture of how it currently looks now.

**UPDATE #2**Starting from the 5th picture, this is now how it is looking. Seems to me like its dying.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

[image: 6]

[image: 7]

[image: 8]

[image: 9]

[image: 10]

[image: 11]

Comment: This plant continues to be grown in low light conditions.  Until you change that weak growth is Likely

Comment: @kevinsky I dont quite understand, are you saying it's getting low light and it needs to be under a bit of heavier sun? And this is why its weak growth (low light)?

Comment: I think thats exactly what Kevin is saying - it wants more sunlight.  I'm not qualified to answer your questions, but we have no problem growing figs in Auckland and we have high humidity, so I'd imagine a humidifier won't hurt it.

Comment: @AlinaMitroi Yes, I water every Saturday. And I let it drain out completely before putting it back.

Comment: Love how you water this plant except for the Saturday thing.  Plants, environments just aren't part of our calendars.  Get used to the heft of your plant, pot when dry and then when soaked.  You'll easily be able to tell if your plant needs water.  This guy needs water now not Saturday and gee I would get a 'grow' light, a real one like 300 watts or more for this plant and also transplant or up pot.  Look for Pot Feet...some are cast as lions claws or scrolls or whatever and look great.  Also a platform with wheels because in a year or two in a properly sized pot he'll be heavy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plant needs more light, replanted in a slightly larger pot (3 to 4" larger in diameter than it is in right now)...sending you a link you might not have seen.  Is this plant somewhere else during the day and resides on this coffee table at night? When you water soak the soil and then allow that soil to dry out before the next watering/soaking.

Please use sterilized bagged potting soil when you up pot. A clay pot (heavier for stability) that is 14 inches in diameter (I am guessing this pot is 10"), has a matching saucer and really you should ask for the 'pot feet'.  This raises the pot bottom off the surface and facilitates drainage big time. And looks cool. Just sterilized potting soil in the pot, no rock or gravel at the bottom of the soil and above the drainage hole.[Fiddle Leaf care](http://www.hgtv.com/outdoors/flowers-and-plants/houseplants/the-fiddle-leaf-fig-is-fashion-forward)

A little Osmocote 14-14-14 twice per year extended release fertilizer is enough and perfect.  This guy won't be hangin' on your coffee table much longer.  Bigger pot, pot feet keep it near the light not in the direct sunlight and leave it right there.  No drafts...indoors weird air flow of different temperatures that have no rhyme or reason kind of piss this plant off big time. Following a piece on equisetum and silica;

"But although not essential for other monocots and dicots, beneficial effects like increased pest and pathogen resistance, drought and heavy metal tolerance and the quality and yield of agricultural crops have been recognized and thus the still unclear pathways and molecular mechanisms of silicon uptake and deposition have become of research interest (Adatia and Besford 1986; Raven 2003; Richmond and Sussman 2003; Ma 2004; Romero-Aranda et al. 2006). Silica is transported as monosilicic acid from the roots to the terminal regions via the transpiration stream and deposited as amorphous silica gel (SiO2·nH2O) in cell lumens, cell walls, and intercellular spaces or external layers (Hartley and Jones 1972; Raven 1983; Epstein 1994). The surface etc...."

Comment: Yes it resides on the coffee table once the sun comes down I move it back to the coffee table.

Comment: How do you think I knew that???  Grins!  Your plant is going to get HUMONGOUS for an indoor plant and it will have to stay by the sun permanently, eventually.  I think you are ready for Bonsai!  How wonderful for your table and YOU.  To be able to keep a Bonsai alive is a test of a gardener.  To be able to grow one from a start and train it is the next step.  Just an idea.

Comment: Ecaxtly, you hit it right on the nose. But that is a good idea. Grins, as well!!

Comment: I've did it, I change to a ceramic pot, changed the dirt and it just flopped. I've had it in the sun. I don't know what's going on. I've added an update picture; take a look.

Comment: Looks fine Lost!  The leaves are wide and thin because they were in a low light situation.  They get big in an effort to gather every bit of light available.  So they are going to be heavy and will not change.  You'll get new growth that is smaller, darker and thicker.  Not to worry.  In this case I say STAKE your plant.  Get a 4 to 5 foot bamboo stake or the green plastic stake poke it in the ground, then tie your main stem to the stake.  Use panty hose or strips of towel to support your plant tied loosely, just enough to give it a little support.  When those leaves finally die cut them off.

Comment: Nice size of pot.  Try to get the bottom of that pot off any surface using pieces of tile or fancy 'pot feet'.  A larger tray in black.  Rotate once in a while.  Have you fertilized?  When was the last time?  Less is best but your plant is looking like it needs nitrogen.  Get Osmocote for houseplants 14-14-14.  Extended release.  Give it a table spoon or two according to directions.  And forget about fertilizers for at least 4 to 6 months before having to administer more.  Those leaves are necessary for the plant now and in the near future to make food. They'll obviously die and you then cut.

Comment: Patience...you are doing quite well!!  It is organic don't panic?  Works with growing any plant, grins.  Keep us apprised, this is a major learning experience that should be made successful....

Comment: Ok so I did fertilize during the transitioning to one pot to the other and watered as well. I used Osmocote as you said. Instead of putting the osmocote on top, as I was replanting, I put some in the middle and continued to add dirt until everything was complete. Should I put some on top now? Or will that just make it worse off? My plant still looks the same as the updated picture; now the very top foliage seems as if it is going to die soon, its already starting to chance color; like a fading away green color. Im truly scared to lose this plant. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @LOSTinNEWYORK Great work!  Did you use the prescribed amount?  As long as you stayed at or below that amount I would go ahead and sprinkler a LITTLE on the surface then 'scruff' it into the soil a bit.  I just don't see any reason this guy won't do well.  Please be patient. You have to send continuing progress pictures.  It is so tough to help from a few words and fewer pictures.  Someone that has had some success with a plant will more likely become a gardener.  A gardener is someone not afraid of plants cause they understand plants are different than us humans.  Keep sending pictures okay?

Comment: @LOSTinNEWYORK  this is tongue in cheek but maybe put a sign up on this plant saying 'IGNORE ME'...secretly send pictures.  Do you know what equisetum or horse tail is?  Let me know if you have it anywhere nearby.  Dried horse tail is an incredible source of silica.  And I know I'll get yelled at but there is a reason this plant is older than the horses it was named after 'horses tail'...100 MILLION years old, trees of this Genus were 100 feet high.  It has been found that the silica 'adds' strength to plants; resistance to disease, resistance to insect, etc.  Added link to my answer above.

Comment: No, I never heard of it but I will search for it in the stores; If they sell it here in NY. Another question, Can I cut the foliage off that are dying? Like theyre are 2 of them that are completely no coming back. If I can cut them off, is their a specific way to do so. Such as cutting them off in a slanted way, rather straight across? The top foliage is completely dead and weak and it is making the next foliage drop down even more. If so, how do I cut it off so another can new foliage can grow after cutting it? Thanks

Comment: @Starting from the 5th picture, thats how my plant is looking now. And those are the ones I was asking whether I can cut off and how to cut them off? Is there a certain way to cut them, so new growth can reproduce

Comment: @LOSTinNEWYORK Those pictures are a bit disturbing.  Are you still using tap water from the city water system?  What exactly have you used for fertilizer.  To me, my initial response is salt or fertilizer burn.  Please give me your answers soon.  Tell me everything you've added in that pot, that soil...soon.

Comment: Yes, I'm using tap water from the cities water system; but I dont see any salt residue at the top of the soil because normally the top soil will turn white. I will add a picture of the fertilizer and soil I used when I changed the pot. Stay tuned...

Comment: I've put up the picture of exactly what I've used.

Comment: @LOSTinNEWYORK  How much fertilizer did you put in that soil?  The soil looks...ok.  I am not a fan of water absorbers in the soil because that inhibits drainage.  Miracle Gro made that soil and they have a propensity of adding fertilizer in their potting soils.  Adding more fertilizer would be bad.  Check that out on the back of your bag...I tried to see what the numbers are for that 'shake' extended release fertilizer.  Your plant edges burning like this looks like too much fertilizer.  If that soil has fertilizer as well, I'd get new soil and dump the soil with too much fertilizer...

Comment: ...gently transplant into boring cheapo bagged sterilized potting soil, get rid of as much of the fertilized soil as you can.  Wash out the pot before putting the new soil in your pot.  Don't add any fertilizer at all!  This SPONGE water absorbing stuff also absorbs fertilizer and holds it in place as well.  Don't know what it does to the extended release mechanisms.  I am so sorry I didn't make things even more detailed and clearer.  This plant doesn't look good at all.  And it happened so quickly I think the problem has to be too much fertilizer....arghhh.

Comment: Tell me how much you used, if you 'shook' help me see the density you remember.  Tell me what is in that soil.  Any additives, fertilizers?  I feel bad, too much fertilizer is kind of a death sentence.  Let me know the answers and I've got more detailed stuff you can do while transplanting (again) IF it is indeed too much fertilizer.  Osmocote extended release is dependable, very minute releases.  I don't know Miracle grow stuff.  I should have told you to hold off with the fertilizer for awhile...

Comment: Just looked up this soil and it DOES have fertilizer already in it to last 6 months.  Ugh.  Adding more fertilizer is what has happened.  Let me know for sure what your bag says on the back. Couldn't find the same packaging.  Get cheap, bagged, sterilized soil with NO fertilizer and NO water absorbing stuff...replace that soil.  The advertising on products is always made confusing so you will likely fail and go back to spend more money.  Tell me what is listed on the back of that soil package...first!

Comment: Ugh, My husband threw the bag away; not knowing that I was saving it to tell you what it says on the back of it. I just got so fed up and scared that I cut from where all the dead foliage was; hopefully I cut the proper way. I didnt want it to spread and kill the other foliage. I emptied out the dirt, cleaned the pot out completely. I only had one brand new bag of dirt made by 'Miracle Grow' which also feeds up to 6 months, smh. So i took as much dirt from the roots as possible and I rinsed it off a bit to get rid of any left over fertilizer and repotted.

Comment: Picture added to show you how I cut off all the dead leaves. My plant is so short now, smh. And hoping it will survive from the cutting

Comment: I didnt add any extra fertilizer like I did before. Just the dirt which still has fertilizer in it

Comment: You are doing the right things!  Your plant already looks better!  You've got a bit of innate understanding with plants...good job.  I mean REALLY good job.  Watch and relax.  Come back with anything you question, OK?  This is such a super learning experience and I so very want you to succeed!

Comment: Thanks Stormy for sticking with me with this plant. We'll see what happens next

Comment: Please, let us know. I feel sorta responsible.  I'll be watching for your questions and comments!

Comment: No worries, dont feel responsible, it was trial and error but I will keep you posted, no worries; dont worry.

Comment: Please send updates.  It would be nice to know there is a way to diagnose and help via the internet.  I like your attitude, LOST!

Comment: I sure will, as time goes by and I see progression.

Comment: It completely died. I literally have an empty pot. I've had it since it was only 3 foliages. Smh. I'm so sad about this.

Comment: Ah shoot.  I am so sorry.  But I LOVE you for feeling this way about a plant.  Seriously appropriate.  Part of your life.  Let's do this again, ok?  Go to a great nursery one that has people that know what they are doing.  Go find a plant and check it's roots, its history, when and what it was fertilized with...get soil without any water holding gels or fertilizers.  I am very impressed that you cared about this plant.  Shows that you are of the upper crust of humans...thank you for feeling about other life like this!  Gotta make mistakes to learn, I wish I had asked more detailed questions.